# Is there a way to inject a string in a linux application, so i can later read it somehow?

Tags: python, linux

I am writing code that looks up the active window with the help of `xprop`

So it's easy when the application is launched from the command line with a `-- command`
i can later read that window with `_WM_COMMAND(STRING)`... But the problem is.. not every software stores the command string..

I need to pass a string to the starting application and somehow read that later. 
Thank you!

Comment: Why should arbitrary programs store your data? Why doesn't your program do it?

Comment: @thatotherguy because its a time logger software that needs to keep track of what the arbitrary programs are doing (not just the name of the program- but what project they are working and what task, etc..)